# Count values from a table and store in variable

Tags: r

I have the following table named `tabela`.

The column `corrida` is the first six numbers of the column `indicado`.
I need to count the number of equal (identical) rows in `corrida` and store in a new variable.

How can I do this?

[image: Table Image]

## **Edit:**

I have tried:

```
tabela <- tabela[(str_sub(tabela$indicado, start = 12, 12) == "0") == T ,] 
tabela$corrida <- as.numeric(str_sub(tabela$indicado, start = 1, 6))
```

Comment: Do you need `table(tabela$indicado)` ?

Comment: Yah.
I already have this:

tabela <- tabela[(str_sub(tabela$indicado, start = 12, 12) == "0") == T ,]
tabela$corrida <- as.numeric(str_sub(tabela$indicado, start = 1, 6))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick (albeit probably not computationally optimal!) solution is to create a separate table that tallies the number of rows that have a given, unique value for 'corrida' and join it back to the original table.

Try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

corridaCounts <- tabela %>%
    group_by(corrida) %>%
    summarise(n = n())

tabelaTally <- tablea %>%
    left_join(corridaCounts, by = "indicado")
```

This will generate a new table (`tableaTally`) that contains the original data and the count of rows that have the given value of `indicado` as variable `n`.

If you just want the table of rows with a given unique value of `indicado`, this is saved as `tableaTally`.

Comment: I'll use this too. When I code that, my program return me this:

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
table(tabela$corrida)
```

Maybe you prefer this:

```
data.frame(table(tabela$corrida) )
```